# Automatic detection of object property type based on another property value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a 'switcher' of an unknown type coming from a database. Basically, there are certain calculation types that have a different data structure and need to be processed differently depending on the type. My first way to solve the problem was using conditionals:

```js
type CalculationTypes = "add" | "average"

export interface Calculation<T extends CalculationTypes> {
  calculationID: string // unique to all calculations
  type: T
  payload: T extends "add" ? CalculationAdd : CalculationAverage 
}

interface CalculationAdd {
  addlist: {referenceContainer: string, referenceID: string}[] 
}

interface CalculationAverage {
  averageList: number[]
}
```

This worked - kind of - because the type wasn't being detected later in the script. I had to infer it, which isn't so bad, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it where the transpiler can automatically deduce the type...

Then later in the script:

```js
    for (const calculation of dbresult.calculations) {
      switch(calculation.type) {
        case "add":
          const payload = calculation.payload as CalculationAdd // <--- this is what I want it to do automatically.
          /** The transpiler does not detect it. It thinks that payload is of
              type CalculationAdd | CalculationAverage **/
          payload.addList // do stuff works now with type inference
          // do more stuff
          break;
        case "average":
          const payload = calculation.payload as CalculationAverage
          payload.averageList  // do stuff
          // do more stuff
          break;
      }
    }
```

Without type inference, typescript gives me the error:

```
Property 'addList' does not exist on type 'CalculationAdd | CalculationAverage'.
  Property 'addList' does not exist on type 'CalculationAverage'
```

So for some reason, typescript has not deduced that it has to be of type CalculationAdd without type inference, even though that's the only possibility given the conditional I set up in the Calculation interface.

How can I change the way I'm defining these types and interfaces so that typescript automatically deduces them?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you map both of them to the same format, so you can look at it on a higher level of abstraction, in a polymorphic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is actually capable of doing this. See this [explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), I think it's very similar with your use-case.

I think your problem comes from the fact that you've defined the same variable `payload` in both switch-case branches. Either try to rename the `payload` in the second case, or just wrap your switch-case branches in curly brackets, `{ ... }`.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
for (const calculation of dbresult.calculations) {
    switch (calculation.type) {
        case "add": {
            const {payload} = calculation; // <--- automatically inferred by TS
            payload.addlist // do stuff works now with type inference
            console.log(payload);
            break;
        }
        case "average": {
            const {payload} = calculation;
            payload.averageList  // do stuff
            console.log(payload);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```